# Reverse map lookup

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have a 1 to 1 map. What's the best way to find keys from values,

i.e.

For examples if the map is this

KEY  VALUE

```
a    1
b    2
c    3 
d    4
```

I want to be able to find that key corresponding to 3 is C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There isn't much you can do about it. Your have options to work with two maps, use multi-key map like one from [Boost Multi-Index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library, or do linear search.

**UPDATE:** The most lightweight out of the box solution seems to be [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html), which stands for bi-directional map.

Answer (score 13):

Say you have a map`<X,Y>`. Build a second structure, perhaps a map`<Y*,X*,Deref>` that enables the reverse lookup but avoids doubling the storage overhead, because, using pointers, there's no need to store each X and Y twice. The second structure simply has pointers into the first.

Comment: Each pointer usually takes 4-8 bytes. Only use this if the pointers are lighter than the objects and the cost for dereference is negligible. Also be careful when deleting entries in `map<X,Y>`, because pointers are invalidated.

Answer (score 12):

The most direct way would be to maintain a parallel map where the values and keys are reversed (since the relationship is one to one).

Answer (score 9):

Given a `std::map` from keys to values, the following function will return a reverse lookup table, a `std::map` from values to keys.

```
    /// Given a map from keys to values, creates a new map from values to keys 
    template<typename K, typename V>
    static map<V, K> reverse_map(const map<K, V>& m) {
        map<V, K> r;
        for (const auto& kv : m)
            r[kv.second] = kv.first;
        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to use (the less known?) [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html):

> Boost.Bimap is a bidirectional maps
>   library for C++. With Boost.Bimap you
>   can create associative containers in
>   which both types can be used as key. A
>   `bimap<X,Y>` can be thought of as a
>   combination of a `std::map<X,Y>` and a
>   `std::map<Y,X>`. The learning curve of
>   bimap is almost flat if you know how
>   to use standard containers. A great
>   deal of effort has been put into
>   mapping the naming scheme of the STL
>   in Boost.Bimap. The library is
>   designed to match the common STL
>   containers.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the map is huge, or you have some other way of knowing that linear search is too slow, I'd start with linear search:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <map>
using std::map;

#include <algorithm>
using std::find_if;

#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
using boost::assign::map_list_of;

typedef map<char, int> Map;
typedef Map::key_type Key;
typedef Map::value_type Pair;
typedef Map::mapped_type Value;


struct finder {
    const Value v;
    finder(const Value& v) : v(v) {}
    bool operator()(const Pair& p) {
        return p.second == v;
    }
};

Map m = map_list_of('a', 1)('b', 2)('c', 3)('d', 4)('e', 5);

int main() {
    Pair v = *find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), finder(3));
    cout << v.second << "->" << v.first << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I'm recently back to using C++ after 20+ years of using other languages so I have quite a bit of rust.  Is there a way to implement finder as an inline lambda function/expression?

Answer (score 4):

A variation on @Robᵩ's answer above that uses a lambda:

```
map<char, int> m = {{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}, {'d', 4}, {'e', 5}};

int findVal = 3;
auto it = find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [findVal](const Pair & p) {
    return p.second == findVal;
});
if (it == m.end()) {
    /*value not found*/
    cout << "*value not found*";
}
else {
    Pair v = *it;
    cout << v.second << "->" << v.first << "\n";
}
```

(thanks to @Nawaz for his/her contribution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828596/1650814)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a really old question but this codeproject article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3016/An-STL-like-bidirectional-map) is a pretty good example of a bidirectional map.

This is an example program that shows how easy it is:

```
 #pragma warning(disable:4503)

    #include "bimap.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using codeproject::bimap;

    int main(void)
    {
      bimap<int,std::string> bm;

      bm[1]="Monday";
      bm[2]="Tuesday";
      bm[3]="Wednesday";
      bm[4]="Thursday";
      bm[5]="Friday";
      bm[6]="Saturday";
      bm[7]="Sunday";

      std::cout<<"Thursday occupies place #"<<bm["Thursday"]<<
                 " in the week (european style)"<<std::endl;
      return 0;
    }
```