# Get all the keys which matches a query in a map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

Say I have more than one key with the same value in a map. Then in that case how do I retrieve all keys that matches a query.

Or, Is there any possibility to tell find operation to search after a specific value.
I am using an `std::map`, C++.

Comment: I suspect that you might be confusing the term "value".  Maps are said to map from keys to value, but I think you are saying value as in "the value of the key", not "the value the key maps to".  If this is the case, a `std::map` will overwrite the old entry if you reuse the same key twice.  `std::multimap` supports multiple uses of the same key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associative containers probably won't help you too much because for `std::map<K, V>` the key happens to be unique and chances that your chosen query matches the ordering relation you used may not be too high. If the order matches, you can use the `std::map<K, V>` members `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()`. For `std::multimap<K, V>` you can also use `equal_range()`.

In general, i.e., if you query isn't really related to the order, you can use `std::copy_if()` to get a sequence of objects matching a predicate:

```
Other other;
// ...
std::vector<Other::value_type> matches;
std::copy_if(other.begin(), other.end(), 
             std::back_inserter(matches), predicate);
```

When copying the elements is too expensive, you should probably consider using `std:find_if()` instead:

```
for (auto it(other.begin());
    other.end() != (it = std::find_if(it, other.end(), predicate));
    ++it) {
   // do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you:

```
void FindKeysWithValue(Value aValue, list<Key>& aList)
{
    aList.clear();

    for_each(iMap.begin(), iMap.end(), [&] (const pair<Key, Value>& aPair)
    {
        if (aPair.second == aValue)
        {
            aList.push_back(aPair.first);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `const pair<Key, Value>&` here.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to iterate over map.

this link may be useful: [Reverse map lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749073/reverse-map-lookup)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you want quick access and you don't mind using some more space, then you maintain another map that gets stored as value, key. In your case, you would need to handle the duplicate values (that you will be storing as keys).

Not a great idea but definitely an option.

Answer (score 0):

A `map` is meant for efficient lookup of keys. Lookup based on values is not efficient, and you basically have to iterate through the map, extracting matches yourself:

```
for(map<A,B>::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
    if(i->second == foo)
        you_found_a_match();
```

If you intend to do this often, you can build up a multimap mapping the other way, so you can efficiently perform a value-based lookup:

```
multimap<B,A> reverse;
for(map<A,B>::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)
    reverse.insert(pair<B,A>(i->second,i->first));
```

You can now easily find the keys with a given value value:

```
matches = reverse.equal_range(value);
for(multimap<B,A>::iterator i = matches.first; i != matches.second; i++)
    A & key = i->second;
```

If these maps aren't going to grow continuously, it may be more efficient to simply maintain a vector > instead, define a comparator for it based on the value, and use equal_range on that instead.