# Getting passing ‘const std::map<int, bool>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] in lambda function

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, lambda, stl

Here is a basic code snippet for which I'm getting an error:

> error: passing ‘const std::map<int, bool>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]`

```cpp
struct Point {
    float x;
    float y;
    int id;
    Point(float x, float y, float id) : x(x), y(y), id(id) {}
};

void removePoints(std::vector<Point> &points_vec) {
    std::map<int, bool> my_map;
    for (const auto& pt : points_vec) {
        if(pt.id < 0) 
            my_map[pt.id] = true;
        else
            my_map[pt.id] = false;
    }

    points_vec.erase(std::remove_if(points_vec.begin(), points_vec.end(), [map_lambda = my_map] (const Point pt) -> bool {
        return map_lambda[pt.id];
    }), points_vec.end());
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::vector<Point> points_vec;
    points_vec.push_back(Point(1, 2, 0));
    points_vec.push_back(Point(1, 5, -1));
    points_vec.push_back(Point(3, 3, -1));
    points_vec.push_back(Point(4, 9, 2));
    points_vec.push_back(Point(0, 1, 3));
    points_vec.push_back(Point(-1, 7, -2));

    std::cout << points_vec.size() << std::endl;
    removePoints(points_vec);
    std::cout << points_vec.size() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I know I can remove points without using `std::map`, but the above code snippet is just an example of a bigger problem.

I checked some questions on a similar error:

1. [error: passing ‘const std::map<int, int>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095642/)
2. [C++ "error: passing 'const std::map<int, std::basic_string<char> >' as 'this' argument of ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277671/)

But in both of them, it was because of the fact that `std::map` has been declared as `const`. On the other hand, the `map` I'm trying to use/access has not been declared as `const`, and my error is also related to a lambda. As you can see, I'm creating a copy of the original `my_map` in the lambda capture list as `map_lambda = my_map`. So, why am I'm getting this `-fpermissive` error? Or, when we capture something in a lambda, does it automatically get converted to `const`?

Detailed error message:

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:26:32: error: passing ‘const std::map<int, bool>’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         return map_lambda[pt.id];
                                ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/map:61:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_map.h:484:7: note:   in call to ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = bool; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, bool> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = bool; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’
       operator[](const key_type& __k)
       ^~~~~~~~
```

On a side note, I know the `operator[]` returns the value if the key already exists, otherwise it creates a new key and inserts the value (and returns it). But why does `const` for `std::map::operator[]` give a compilation error? Shouldn't it be more of like a runtime error instead?

Answer (score 4):

All variables captured by lambda are implicitly `const`, unless you mark lambda as `mutable`. There is no `const` overload for `operator[]` for map, because it may always change the map (create new key-value pair).

If you are sure that every `pt.id` exists in the map, change `operator []` to `at()` call:

```
[map_lambda = my_map] (const Point pt) -> bool {
        return map_lambda.at(pt.id);
}
```

If you want to create keys in the map if they are not present, change lambda to `mutable`:

```
[map_lambda = my_map] (const Point pt) mutable -> bool {
        return map_lambda[pt.id];
}
```

Comment: Note that in `[map_lambda = my_map]`, `map_lambda` will be a *copy* of `my_map`, so `my_map` will not be altered in any way, no matter what happens to `map_lambda`.  If you need to update `my_map`, capture it by reference instead, eg `[&map_lambda = my_map]`, or even just `[&my_map]` or `[&]` since it doesn't really need a separate name in this example.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for these tips :) Just to confirm, apart from capturing `my_map` by reference, I also have to change lambda to `mutable`, correct? Because, as @Yksisarvinen mentioned above, without `mutable`, it would like `const` reference, right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Yksisarvinen. As you mentioned *"There is no const overload for operator[] for map, because it may always change the map (create new key-value pair)."*. But I'm still a little bit confused: shouldn't that be a runtime error? Thanks again!

Comment: @Milan "*I also have to change lambda to `mutable`, correct?*" - yes, you would need `mutable`, otherwise `my_map` will be captured by a `const` reference, thus preventing use of `map::operator[]`.

Comment: @Milan "*shouldn't that be a runtime error?*" - no. It does not make sense to allow non-const methods to be called on `const` objects. And `operator[]` has to be non-const so it can mutate the `map`'s contents. This is simply part of how const-correctness works in C++

Comment: Thanks a lot, @RemyLebeau . Just to confirm a few things: so if the object is `const` then it doesn't matter whether it's a const method (i.e. `const` at the end of function declaration) or non-const method, right? And in the above case, `map` object has been implicitly converted to `const`. So, `operator[]` can't do anything and that's how `const-correctness` works in C++... this is like a set of defined rules or like standard, correct? Thanks again :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231764/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-milan).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the lambda expression used in this statement

```
 points_vec.erase(std::remove_if(points_vec.begin(), points_vec.end(), [map_lambda = my_map] (const Point pt) -> bool {
        return map_lambda[pt.id];
    }), points_vec.end());
```

is immutable. So `map_lambda` is considered as a constant object.  But the subscript operator requires that the object would be modifiable. That is you may not use the subscript operator with a constant object of the class template `std::map`.

You should declare `map_lambda` as a non-constant reference to `my_map`.

That is change the lambda like

```
[&map_lambda = my_map] (const Point pt) -> bool {
        return map_lambda[pt.id];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad from Moscow for your answer... but as @Yksisarvinen pointed out above, unless I use `mutable`, anything captured in lambda would be implicitly converted to `const`, right? So, wouldn't that be a `const` reference? Please correct me if I'm mistaken. Thanks again!

Comment: @Milan I showed how a non-constant reference to the original map is declared n the lambda.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but wouldn't `[&map_lambda = my_map]` without `mutable` is a `const` reference? Sorry but now I got a little bit more confused because as @Remy Lebeau pointed out about, I need `mutable` otherwise it will be `const` reference!

Comment: @Milan No it will not. be a constant reference

Comment: Thank you @Vlad, I tried out what you said and it looks like if I use reference in the capture list then I can't modify the captured objects, even without `mutable`. So, just to confirm, `mutable` comes into the picture only when I capture something by value, right? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Milan You can modify the captured object.

Comment: no no, I'm talking about capturing something by value and then modifying (or say, trying to modify) it without using `mutable`... just like my code snippet in the main question. So, I just anted to confirm, `mutable` is useful only while capturing something by value, correct?

Comment: @Milan In this case you need to use the specifier mutable.